# sidebar with materialIcons

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom control, that I mad, for hosting the name, and icon of the panel, and made triggers, so it will change colors when I hover the icon or select it

```
  public class NavButton : ListBoxItem {
    static NavButton() {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NavButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NavButton)));
    }

    public Uri NavLink {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(NavLinkProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NavLinkProperty, value); }
    }

    // This property will hold specifics on where to navigate within our appreciation
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NavLinkProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "NavLink", typeof(Uri),
            typeof(NavButton),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));


    // This property will hold specifics on the icon
    public Label Icon {
        get { return (Label)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Icon.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon",
            typeof(Label),
            typeof(NavButton),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

The problem is, that whenever I call  this control in my main, I always get this error

[image: eror]

I am calling it like this

```
<custom:NavButton
                Padding="6"
                FontFamily="{StaticResource Material}"
                Icon="{x:Static fonts:IconFont.VolumeHigh}"/>
```

And this is the recourse dictionary for the label

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <FontFamily x:Key="Material">/Fonts/Material.ttf#Material Design Icons</FontFamily>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NavButton}">

        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:NavButton}">
                    <Border
                        x:Name="back"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="8">
                        <Label
                            x:Name="icon"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource Material}"
                            FontSize="48"
                            Foreground="#7b8793" />
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="back" Property="Background" Value="#d0ebff" />
                            <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="Foreground" Value="#2a84f1" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="back" Property="Background" Value="#d0ebff" />
                            <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="Foreground" Value="#2a84f1" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: error message clearly says, that you have a type mismatch. `Icon` DP should not have type Label. it should have the same type as `IconFont.VolumeHigh`

Comment: So how can I fixed that

Comment: I have a class named IconFont, where I have all the Icons

Comment: I wrote how you fix that: "Icon DP should not have type Label. it should have the same type as IconFont.VolumeHigh"

Comment: jajaja so Icon font will be the type? what I do not understand is that I use those material icons in labels, so why it should be in IconFont

Comment: I already tried it and because my Icon font is a static class, it doesn't like it

Comment: how is IconFont class implemented? what is VolumeHigh? please make them a part of [mcve]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248813/discussion-between-eduardo-gomez-and-ash).

Answer (score 1):

error message clearly says, that you have a type mismatch. `Icon` DP should not have type Label. it should have the same type as `IconFont.VolumeHigh`. or it could simple be `object`:

```
// This property will hold specifics on the icon
public object Icon {
    get { return (Label)GetValue(IconProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Icon.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Icon",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(NavButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: I tried this and dosent work